# Python input or raw input (2.7.15)

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I'm new to python. I'm working on MacOS and I have python 2.7.15.

I'm trying to get input from the user :

```
#these two rows do not execute at the same time, it's just an example :)
annee = raw_input("Saisissez une annee : ") #works if input is string, but not if it's int
annee = input("Saisissez une annee : ") #works if input is int, but not if it's string
try:
    anne = int(annee)
    # isBissextile(annee)
except:
    print("Erreur lors de la saisie")
```

As said in my comments, input and raw_input are not working as expected, I want to be able to get the input either int or string, and then show exception or not

Comment: What strings are you expecting? whats wrong with parsing the users input?

Comment: I assume that you want to input a numeric like figure here right? then you can just use input() and parse it via int(). it will work with 123 or '123'

Comment: @Sayse I want to avoid input.

Comment: @Roel yes, I want only to read integer (for example, a year)

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want it? It is doing the same thing though.

```
try:
    annee = int(input("Saisissez une annee : "))
except:
    print("Erreur lors de la saisie")
```